# Does not recognize the error and crashes the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When a person writes an incorrect link, the bot sends a message that he started looking for a song and just turns off. In this case, the catch method does not work. Is it possible to somehow check if the link is correct and if it is incorrect to issue an error?

Code:

```
const { EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder, ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require("discord.js");
const client = require("../../index");
const Schema = require("../../Models/Music");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("Playing song.")
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("song")
                .setDescription("Provide a link to the song/title.")
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const { options, member, guild, channel } = interaction;

        Schema.findOne({ Guild: member.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
            if (!data) {
                const embed = new EmbedBuilder();

                embed.setColor("Red").setDescription(`The music channel is not installed! Install with the command \`/music setup.\` or ask to install Administrators.`);
                return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
            }
            let channell = data.Channel;
            let channellllllll = data.TextChannel;

        const query = options.getString("трек");
        const voiceChannel = member.voice.channel;
        const channelll = member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.Channel);
        const channellll = member.guild.channels.cache.get(data.TextChannel);
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder();
        
        if (channel !== channellll) {
            embed.setColor("Red").setDescription(`Music commands can only be used in the channel ${channellll}!`);
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
        }

        if (voiceChannel !== channelll) {
            embed.setColor("Red").setDescription(`You must be connected to a voice channel ${channelll}, to execute musical commands.`);
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
        }

        if (!voiceChannel) {
            embed.setColor("Red").setDescription(`You must be connected to a voice channel ${channelll}, to execute musical commands.`);
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
        }

        if (!member.voice.channelId == guild.members.me.voice.channelId) {
            embed.setColor("Red").setDescription(`You cannot use the music player because it is already active in the channel <#${guild.members.me.voice.channelId}>`);
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });
        }


        try {

            client.distube.play(voiceChannel, query, { textChannel: channel, member: member });
            return interaction.reply({ content: ` Looking for a track on request \`${query}\`...`, ephemeral: true });

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);

            const errEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("Red")   
                .setDescription(`Error: \`${err}\``);

                return interaction.reply({ embeds: [errEmbed], ephemeral: true, components: [but] });
            }
    }
    )}
}
```

Error:

```
D:\v144\node_modules\distube\dist\index.js:1010
      throw new DisTubeError("NOT_SUPPORTED_URL");
            ^

DisTubeError [NOT_SUPPORTED_URL]: This url is not supported
    at DisTubeHandler.resolve (D:\v144\node_modules\distube\dist\index.js:1010:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DisTube.play (D:\v144\node_modules\distube\dist\index.js:2279:14) {
  errorCode: 'NOT_SUPPORTED_URL'
}
```

I'm trying to make sure that the bot does not turn off but tracks the error.

Comment: You have to `await` the promise when using a try/catch.

Comment: @Elitezen Can I please have an example?

Comment: Since your function is `async`, you can use the `await` keyword to await a promise and handle any error, add await before the line which throws an error: `await client.distube.play...`